# Filter out unused emails newsletters, info from catch all mail address

Tags: gmail

I'm having trouble with my email accounts that are deleted from Gapps (free license). But this question is legitimate for any situation (mail server).

Thing is that I had several accounts that were registered on various websites which are sending regular updates, newsletters etc. But those accounts are no longer used and are deleted, so my `catch all` filter gets a lot of "junk".

I am aware that `catch all`  is actually "junk collector".

But still is it somehow possible to filter out some e-mails for good?

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you for grammar and spell check I will learn a lot from it.
Regarding the question it seems it is really easy to do.

Just go to gmail settings and use filters, the hard part was to find out specific content in emails that occures just in the email messages sent to mail accounts that are no longer active.

Mails are comming just from facebook and twitter so it was easy to filter them out and automatically send them to trash.